# react: HTML custom element fails to update under one scenario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I am wondering if anyone has theories on what to try

One of the devs on my team is using wrapped custom HTML components from another team (the wrapper is basically Robin Weiruch's https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-custom-element except made into Typescript).

The odd behavior is that the 2nd "select" does not follow the first when the checkbox is checked *if and only if the 2nd select had been changed*.  It will follow the first if the first is changed after the checkbox is checked.

[image: UI]

I refactored the code from a `useState` to a `useReducer` -- as the wrapped components update, they do cause subsequent change events (and extra dispatch calls) *except* in the problem scenario [the change event doesn't fire **the first time** -- it's like its stuck in a debounce]

any theories on what to try?

thanks

Comment: Ended up punting and wrapping it ins useCallback, suppressing the dependency warning

Answer (score 0):

useCallback with a warning suppression worked

A better way of dealing with an external component that misbehaves on its understanding of state is still desirable